# How to launch PWAs from the terminal (Microsoft Edge Apps / Chromium Apps)

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, chromium, browser, microsoft

I have websites such as Notion, Outlook, and Onedrive installed as Apps through the edge browser. I wanted to know if they can be launched using a command in the terminal.

I've used the following command to get the window class string

```
$ xprop -notype | grep -Eo '^(WM_CLASS|_NET_WM_NAME) = "[^"]*"'
```

which returns this for Notion:

```
_NET_WM_NAME = "Action Zone"
WM_CLASS = "crx__meenihjdjcobmkkapcdapdakmpbfpjeo"
```

And this for a normal edge tab:

```
_NET_WM_NAME = "New tab and 13 more pages - Personal - Microsoft​ Edge"
WM_CLASS = "microsoft-edge"
```

Now, while the command `microsoft-edge` can be used in the terminal to launch it, `crx__meenihjdjcobmkkapcdapdakmpbfpjeo` cannot. What do i need to do instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out how to get this to work, for those wondering i'll post the solution below.

To find out which command you need, just

Navigate in edge to `edge://apps/`

1. Right click on the desired app and select "Create Shortcuts"
2. Create a shortcut to the desktop
3. Open the shortcut using a text editor and extract the command. (Exec)

Now, using this command, you can execute the app directly from the terminal
In my case I can do it by issuing the following command:

```
/opt/microsoft/msedge/microsoft-edge --profile-directory=Default --app-id=meenihjdjcobmkkapcdapdakmpbfpjeo --app-url=https://www.notion.so/Action-Zone-d7c525a18e4a453d9ba64c62505bf576
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks for this. Now I can run MS Teams with GPU disabled (--disable-gpu) so my laptop doesn't sound like a jet engine in calls